# Turn revisions off in plugin instead of config.php?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-config, revisions

Is there a function to set WP_POST_REVISIONS from a plugin instead of having to do it in config.php?  I was thinking of doing this:

```
runkit_constant_redefine( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 0 );
```

but that puts a dependency on runkit being compiled in with PHP which I'm not sure is usual/typical.

I want to turn revisions off completely and I'd like my (narrow use, special purpose) plugin to be as "turnkey" as possible; not requiring other tweaks or manual adjustments.

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?

Comment: @jgraup  I ended up sticking with my delete_revisions function for now.  I'm working on another part of the system but will loop back to your suggestion at some point...thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a no-revs.php
2. Set the contents to `<?php defined('WP_POST_REVISIONS') or define ('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);`
3. Place it in the [Must Use Plugins Folder](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) located at `wp-content/mu-plugins`.

Be warned; It is [recommended](http://www.wpstuffs.com/how-to-limit-post-revisions-in-wordpress-without-plugin/) that you to have at least 3 post revisions to avoid any loss of data.

Comment: Doesn't core already define the constant and that logic will never get past the 'or' ?

Comment: It worked when I tested it. I'd give it a shot and let me know if it doesn't work for you. I'm on the latest WP and I can check again w/ the 4.4 release tomorrow.

Comment: ok thanks...in the meantime I coded a simple function that cleans up revisions, hooked to 'shutdown'.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the `wp_revisions_to_keep` filter to override the value of the `WP_POST_REVISIONS` constant:

```
/**
 * Turn off revisions
 */
add_filter( 'wp_revisions_to_keep', function( $num, $post )
{
    //---------------------------------
    // Adjust the $num to your needs
    //---------------------------------
    if ( post_type_supports( $post->post_type, 'revisions' ) )
        $num = 0;

    return $num;

}, PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
```

If `$num` is `-1` then we keep all revisions.
If `$num` is `0` then we don't keep them.

To turn it off we could also try to remove the *revisions support* with [remove_post_type_support()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support):

```
/**
 * Remove revisions support for posts
 */
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    remove_post_type_support( $post_type = 'post', $supports = 'revisions' );
} );
```

Comment: very cool, thank you.  I'll have to experiment with this.  I need it to work on post_type='page' -- and I want to keep the single autosave revision around (in case the user left the editor without saving).  The cleanup function I wrote is working this way but it would be good to stop it at the onset rather than clean up, later.  I wonder if the hook / function you cited above will leave 'autosave' alone or if they will turn that off, too (since autosave is technically a type of revision) (?)